# Insert data with another table

Tags: mysql

I have update data one table to another below mentioned query is working fine but it takes so much time because I am updating 400000 records.

Can anyone can help me so that it takes less time.

```
update gtp_master_account a set a.branch_name = 
(Select name from gtp_bank_data b where a.bank_iso_code = b.bic);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update gtp_master_account a 
join gtp_bank_data b on a.bank_iso_code = b.bic
set a.branch_name = b.name;
```

its query takes less time.

because in your query, check condition one by one and update it.
by using join, all record fetch and update at the time of record fetch.